# ssh agent forwarding not working on ec2

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-agent

I'm trying to use ssh agent forwarding on my local machine so that I dont have to use my private key on remote server for `git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/bucketname.git`

I have following setup on my machine:

```
 $cat ~/.ssh/config
    Host bitbucket.org
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    Host 172.28.128.3
     ForwardAgent yes
```

and have added my public key to bitbucket site

when i run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` it shows

```
logged in as <username>.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

means ssh protocol working right and I can clone any repo.

But when I run on my remote machine/host  ( mentioned in .ssh/config file with ip 172.28.128.3)

```
buntu@remoteMachine$ ssh -vT git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I am using ec2 instance as remote machine.

please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: did you add your identity to the agent? You can verify by running `ssh-add -l` on your local machine. This should also work on remote one to verify it is forwarded successfully.

Comment: i got this. Actually I was running ssh command as sudo to login to ec2 instance. When i ran it withoute sudo, it worked !!

Comment: @PremSompura I am also facing same problem. In my local my using "abc" user while ssh into ec2 server I use "abc" user but ec2 having "ubuntu" user.. will this create problem ?

Comment: @PushkerYadav You need to forward your ssh agent. Try adding your agent via ssh-add and use ssh -A user@host to login.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend this link to set up ssh forwarding agent
[Guide for SSH Agent Forwarding](https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/)

Try troubleshooting it like this:

1. Check you have written correct Host IP in your local machine `.ssh/config`
2. On your local machine, run this command --> `echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"`

2.1. If this gives empty response, then do this: `` eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add -k ``

3. Everything should be working now