# VSCode Agent forwarding not working from Windows to Linux

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, remote-access

I have the following development setup: Windows PC (Client) connects to Linux PC (Workstation). On the Windows client I open VSCode and use the remote connection. Authentification is set up using openssh (according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) and automatic login in VScode works.

Things do not work anymore when I want to clone a repository from Github on the workstation. If I run "Git: Clone" in VSCode, I get a "permission denied (publickey)" error. Same happens when running the command in a terminal within VSCode. I can use the same ssh agent (incl. key) however natively on Windows to clone the repo (Github authentication works with that key).

I was following the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39866194/3045875 and checked through the guide: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/using-ssh-agent-forwarding
(I was unable to fully understand what the difference between sshd_config and ssh_config (under /etc and ~ is). Now I have sshd_config AgentForwarding enabled and not specified under ssh_config.

In a VSCode remote terminal I do see that $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set:

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/run/user/1001/vscode-ssh-auth-sock-1737837
```

In Windows I see the agent is running:

```
$ Get-Service ssh-agent

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent
```

I do have ~/.ssh/config on Windows containing:

```
Host xxx
  HostName xxx
  User username
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by upgrading to the latest openssh version (V9.2) on Windows by running `winget install "openssh beta"`.
Reference: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH

Comment: This answer may not fix the OPs problem but this actually fixed my VScode devcontainer extension throwing a "Error: connect ENOENT \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent" error! happy about that. Hoping this comment is found by other people searching for my issue.

Comment: Using this solution, I fixed my problem where "ssh-add -l" shows forwarded keys, but ssh -T git@github.com responds with "Permission denied" error. In the debug log I saw these lines: "channel 1: chan_shutdown_read: shutdown() failed for fd 7 [i0 o0]: No socket" and "get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed".

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions i've seen worked for me, so i decide to post how i've managed to fix it

For some reason when i ran `ssh-add -l` on my local machine it didn't list any of the keys, so i had to add them manually with `ssh-add /path_to/private_key`. Then after i rebooted my pc and tried to connect via ssh from vscode with `ForwardAgent yes` setting in my .ssh/config  enabled everything began to work